# Should we unschedule Sling Jobs running within AEM after they are completed?

Tags: scheduled-tasks, aem, sling, aem-6

I am creating multiple SlingJobs on the fly using `org.apache.sling.commons.scheduler.Scheduler` OSGi service in AEM.

i.e. `scheduler.schedule(Runnable, ScheduleOptions);`

I have requirement that these **Sling Jobs be run only once**, so I am using `ScheduleOptions.AT(Date date,int times,long period)` [ScheduleOptions Docs](https://sling.apache.org/apidocs/sling7/org/apache/sling/commons/scheduler/Scheduler.html#AT-java.util.Date-int-long-)

And passing `times=1` as a parameter.

(Also what is `period` parameter ?)

The Job successfully runs only once.

My question is **am I supposed to keep a track of this Job by name and UnSchedule it** using `Scheduler.unschedule(String jobName)` after it has finished running ?

**Will completed SlingJobs that are not UnScheduled, consume memory in the AEM server ?**

**Will these completed BUT unscheduled jobs cause my AEM server to slow down and later on require some purge activity as maintenance?**

Answer (score 0):

According to https://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/apache-sling-eventing-and-job-handling.html#scheduled-jobs

Internally the scheduled Jobs use the Commons Scheduler Service. **But in addition they are persisted (by default below /var/eventing/scheduled-jobs)** and survive therefore even server restarts. When the scheduled time is reached, the job is automatically added as regular Sling Job through the JobManager.

I had a problem with a scheduled jobs before(they were triggered on the daily basis). When the server was restarted scheduled jobs wasn't un-persisted and a new job doing the same action was scheduled(job was scheduled on @Activate method). As a result, I got several jobs doing the same action at the scheduled time, so I had to unschedule them in @Deactivate method.

You may make an experiment and make sure that there is no duplicated jobs under /var/eventing/scheduled-jobs